# Android Push Notification with different Click activity

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have 'n' number of activities in my app,based on the received notification i have to open the particular activity.
example:if i receive chat it should open chat activity,if i receive request it should open request page and so on.. 
How to implement that? i have searched but didnt find any solution.

```
enter code here

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, main.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            msg.append(newMessage + "\n");
        }
    };
```

Comment: How will you identify what kind of notification received?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, main.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

You're creating and displaying a notification with an intent (`Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, main.class)`). Change the intent based on the behavior you want!

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the message contents and according to that set your preference for the activity to open

```
if(msg_content==something)
{
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, main.class);
 }
else if()
 {.....
  .....}
  else
 {...}
```

change the main.class to your desired activity